# What is a good transition word or phrase to establish or allude to a parallel?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, discourse-markers

I am looking for a word or phrase to replace "similarly" in the following sentence:

> "The obligation from making a promise is an obligation *to* someone; **similarly**, the wrong in breaking a promise is an interpersonal wrong, specifically a wrong against the person to whom the obligation was made."

"Similarly" seems too imprecise and doesn't convey the meaning I am trying to establish. I am tempted to use a word like "therefore," but I mean to indicate that the halves of the sentence should be thought of as parallel and not necessarily that the second follows from the first.

Comment: ***analogously***?

Comment: Likewise would work

Comment: I'm not sure that you can  *make* an obligation. An obligation usually *arises* as a result of something. It might arise as the result of a commitment that you had made. Thus the wrong would be against the person to whom you are obliged.

Answer (score 1):

This phrase, perhaps?

**By the same token**

> used to mean that something you are about to say is also true, for the same reasons as what has just been said:

*I don't think that prices will go up but, by the same token, I don't see them going down either.*

[Cambridge]

Comment: This usually has the added (more overt) implication that a value judgement is being made by the annotator [[CollinsCobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/by-the-same-token)].

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **equivalently** or **likewise** will work for you:

> #### Equivalent
>
> - Having the same value, use, and meaning.
>
> *"...obligation to someone; **equivalently**, the wrong..."*

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivalent))

> #### Likewise
>
> - In the same way; in like manner; similarly.
>
> *"...obligation to someone; **likewise**, the wrong..."*

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likewise))

Comment: Why the downvote? Likewise fits!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand your sentence

> Making a promise is an obligation to a person, ***(just) as*** breaking a promise is a wrong against the person to whom the promise was
> made.

***(just) as*** can be

> used to indicate by comparison the way that something happens or is done. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=as%20meaning&safe=strict&biw=1372&bih=661&sxsrf=ALeKk02F_xaB2lJit2ZAYhk4p_LiDlyHcg%3A1625314407402&ei=Z1TgYNqNGIeL8gK47JRY&oq=as%20mean&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIECCMQJzIECAAQQzIFCAAQkQIyBQgAELEDMgIIADIHCAAQhwIQFDICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6BQguELEDOgIILkoECEEYAFCVdljSeWDhgwFoAnACeACAAacBiAHFBJIBAzIuM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz))

There are other synonym phrases like:

> ***in the same manner (way) that***

or

> ***correspondingly*** which means *in a way that is similar to, connected with, or caused by something else* ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/correspondingly))

[This site](https://students.unimelb.edu.au/academic-skills/explore-our-resources/developing-an-academic-writing-style/connecting-ideas-in-writing) provides more information about ***Connectives***.